# using "field view" with contextual filter

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I'm using the "field view" module that give you the ability to put multuple viens in a Content Type. Thanks to that Content Type, I can put multiple views in one web page, it's very great.

Now I made a view with a contextual filter on a taxonomy, so When I use the normal view I put http://test.local/nameOfMyView/133 (133 is a termId), all works good but when I want to put this view in my Content type, I can't use the termId (http://test.local/content/nameOfTheNode/133 give the 404.

I saw "PLACEHOLDER TOKEN". I think it could be the resolution but I don't know wich one use to relay the termId from the URL to all the view I included in the same content type

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I tried answering this over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15491704/2036095

You could try putting it directly in the node.tpl.php template with:

```
<?php print views_embed_view('view_name', 'default', $arg); ?>
```

Just get the term id and pass it as an argument.