# Using token to pass id in url fron node to view (using viewfield)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I have a page made with view that get a termId from url and that show users attached to this termId (for example) : www.example.com/my-view/122 show me all users that contains the termId 122

By default, if I didn't specify any terms, this page show all the users. (www.example.com/my-view)

Now I put this page (my-view) in a node thanks to the viewfield module and I want to pass the argument to the view included from the node (the term 122), so I expect I have to use TOKENS as specified but I'm not able to use them correctly.

In fact, when I include the page (my-view) in the node, I see the default view when i didn't provide any terms. Once I try to use tokens, nothing appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't have to use tokens : when you use contextual filter, you can provide a default value (value from URL in your case).

Then you can acces to container node by his ID with the therm ID as a suffix, to avoid 404 error.

Normaly it should work !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about passing token values as an argument for viewfields, but you could certainly use contextual filters:

Add a Content: Has taxonomy term ID Contextual Filter in the view (under Advanced), When the filter value is NOT available select "Provide a default value" and chose Taxonomy Term ID from URL. This should add the Term ID as an argument when available.

OR

do it in the node.tpl.php template with:

```
<?php print views_embed_view('view_name', 'default', $arg); ?>
```

Just get the term id and pass it as an argument.

Comment: Ok thanks. I had already set the contextual filter and it works... but when I add a token in the Content Type tnat have the viewfields, it brokes the system